# Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() in StartupNextInstance Event

Tags: vb.net

I'm having trouble trying to get `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` to work in the `StartupNextInstance` event the way it does in the form's `Load` event. The code below checks to see if the application got command line arguments and sends the file path to the `FileOpen()` function, which basically opens the file in my program by taking the file name into its parameters.

```
If Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length > 1 Then FileOpen(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(1))
```

The code above works perfectly in the `Load` event, although it doesn't work in in the `StartupNextInstance` event. I also tried the code below to get the file path of the command line args:

```
Private Sub MyApplication_StartupNextInstance(sender As Object, e As ApplicationServices.StartupNextInstanceEventArgs) Handles Me.StartupNextInstance
    Dim strFile As String = Environment.CommandLine
    If strFile.Length > 0 Then frmMain.FileOpen(strFile)
End Sub
```

The problem with the code above is that it's not getting the file path, instead of getting the file that was used to open the program (with the Open with... method, when you right click on a file), it would open up the location of the program's exe file.

When I tried e.CommandLine I get a error saying:

> Value of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)' cannot be converted to 'String'.

Comment: You can handle the [StartupNextInstance Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startupnextinstance(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Where is that? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Go into your project properties, under the `Application` tab you will find a button that says `Application Events`. Press is to generate the event file, then from the left combo box in the code editor you select the item called something like `MyApplicaton (Events)`. Then in the right combo box you choose `StartupNextInstance`.

Comment: @VisualVincent My code above doesn't run at all, works in the form load event, but not in the `StartupNextInstance`

Comment: The event args of the `StartupNextInstance` event should have a property for the new command line parameters passed to the application, try using that. It should be something like `e.CommanLine`.

Comment: @VisualVincent Still doesn't work, I'm trying to get the file name of the file used to open, (When the user clicks Open with...)

Comment: What do you get then? Could you update the question with your latest code?

Comment: I updated my code, all i'm trying to do is get the file name of the file that was opened with my program and send it to OpenFile() in the StartupNextInstance event

Comment: Show the full event subscription please. And as I said, in that event you are supposed to use `e.CommandLine` instead of `Enviroment.GetCommandLineArgs()`

Comment: e.CommandLine gives me an error.

Comment: What error?? There are thousands of errors. Will you please edit your question and include the entire event sub that you've made? I cannot help you because I don't see the whole picture. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent Alright, I updated my post.

Comment: Like the error says, `e.CommandLine` is a collection just like the `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` array. The only difference is that the application path is not included. Use it like this `Dim strFile As String = e.CommandLine(0)`

Comment: Worked, thank you so much!

Comment: @visualvincent you have seemed to have answered his question in the comments. Please put the solution in an answer instead.

Comment: @MarkHall Wow hi, I've seen you all around stack overflow, you have some great answers! You've helped me a lot throughout my coding.

Comment: Thank you. I am glad to have been of help.

Comment: @MarkHall : Okay, will do. Haven't had the time earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle your application's [StartupNextInstance event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startupnextinstance(v=vs.110).aspx) and use the `e.CommandLine` parameter to retrieve a list of all newly passed arguments.

```
Private Sub MyApplication_StartupNextInstance(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupNextInstanceEventArgs) Handles Me.StartupNextInstance
    If e.CommandLine.Count > 0 Then frmMain.FileOpen(e.CommandLine(0))
End Sub
```

Apart from `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`, `e.CommandLine` doesn't contain the application's executable path as the first item.

Comment: Do you recommend that I use e.CommandLine in the form `Load` event?

Comment: @Yezetee : No, because it's impossible. `e.CommandLine` exists only in the `StartupNextInstance` event :). --- `e` is the event arguments passed to the event, and as you see in the declaration it uses another class than just `EventArgs`: `ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupNextInstanceEventArgs`.